# Seaborn FacetGrid Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

is it possible to create a stacked barchart facetgrid with seaborn?

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="city", col_order=cities, col_wrap=3, height=5)
g = g.map(plt.plot, x="date", y="value", hue='time_bin', stacked=True, marker=".")
```

unfortunately does not work.

Comment: Can you provide sample data? What's `cities`?

Comment: @QuangHoang cities is just a list of city names :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can guess from your code, it can be done with `plt`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,3,figsize=(12,20))
axes = axes.flatten()

for city,ax in zip(cities,axes):
    df = data[data.city==city].groupby(['date','time_bin']).value.count()
    df.unstack().plot.bar(ax=ax, stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Pretty amazing, its sort of the same solution I ended up with :D Although its not seaborn, is it?